# tool platform io Lost, want to know how to open it up

Tags: visual-studio-code, platformio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWY6g.png)

tool platform io  Lost, want to know how to open it up

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.